# How to correctly store user secrets in a frontend Application?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, key-management

I am building a Web Application where the user's data is end-to-end-encrypted.

The web client obviously needs a secret that nobody else knows for end-to-end-encryption to work.

I have planned to have the user choose a password and then derive an encryption key from it.

Currently, the user has to enter his password again, once he reloads my single-page-app, as the secret is not stored on disk, because storing it in localstorage is probably bad from a security standpoint.

In a native app I'd use something like the keychain to securely store such secrets. What would I use on the web?

I know the [Credential Management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API) exists, this  doesn't work for me because Safari on iOS doesn't support it.

What are the best practices to store user secrets on device from a Web Application? (Preferably without user interaction when retrieving the stored password)

Comment: Isn't that what https and security certificates do automatically? There's information here about best practice: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/security/https . Regarding localstorage, security is only an issue if the remote device is shared.

Comment: End-to-end-encryption ensures that only the user can decrypt the data. My server should not be able to decrypt or read it.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to enable end to end encryption within the browser, it is
> possible to do via javascript (Not Completely though, due to the below
> reasons).

> Proton mail claims that it has end to end encryption enabled in its
> service and is possible via a Javascript file that is shared by the
> server to the client(end-user).

> However, a researcher challenged that it's not completely end to end
> encrypted. He explains that if the server is compromised, and a
> malicious javascript is sent by the server to the client, the server
> can read all its private key. You can read more about the blog and
> research paper and discussion here:

- https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1121.pdf
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonMail/comments/9yqxkh/an_analysis_of_the_protonmail_cryptographic/

> This blog shows how it's possible to create a key using javascript
> which cannot be accessed by the server, but the challenge here is that
> you share the url to the end user via a different channel.

- https://blog.excalidraw.com/end-to-end-encryption/

**Possible Solution:**

> We can let the client generate a private key locally and store the
> public key associated with it, on the server. However to decrypt the
> message, it will require the private key again. For this we can make
> use of browser extensions that will store the private keys, and decode
> the messages on the fly (client Side).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know how key generation works and that there is a problem if the server sends a malicious JavaScript. What I want to know is how to store the secret key in the frontend. Storing it in localstorage seems insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Just for you to know, the [Credential Management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API) you mentioned in the post is now supported by all major browsers (including Safari on iOS).